# Remove parse.com activity indicator

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, uiactivityindicatorview

How do i remove parse's built-in activity indicator?

I have my own activity indicator and i don't want to use two different activity indicators.

This is what activity indicator parse uses when fetching data to a tableview.

[image: Parse's built-in activity indicator]

Comment: Just to clarify - you mean the spinner and "Loading..." message on the PFTableViewController, right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're using a PFTableViewController instead of rolling your own? You wouldn't have this issue if you subclassed UITableViewController instead.

Comment: I know, but is it possible to disable it?

Comment: I think you will save a lot of time using either UITableViewController or a really solid substitute like Sensible Table Views (www.sensiblecocoa.com)

Comment: I will go ahead and create a regular UITableViewController. Thanks for your help!